# Can packer.io template specify processor type in azure builder?

Tags: azure, packer

Constraints:

- My application requires SSE4.2 instruction set.
- I am using packer.io to provision my Windows Azure VM (OpenLogic 6.5 OS.)
- Windows Azure returns an AMD-processor-backed-VM about 15% of the time. The rest of the time - they are Intel-processor-based. AMD processors do not support SSE4.2, but they do support SSE4a. So, my application is terminated with SIGILL on AMD processors.

Questions:

1. Can I request specific architecture (Intel CPU) when Packer
   provisions a VM? I know that instance types >= A8 come only with Intel processors, but they are more expensive, and I would not want to use them for development.
2. If Packer cannot do it, what are the other options
   (Powershell, ect...) that would give me this functionality?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question. Azure does not provide a way to request processor type. The only way to ensure Intel processor is to not use A-series machines (as confirmed by a MSFT representative.) Thus, no tool can do it.